# Using newton-raphson method to generate following schemes

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Using newton's raphson method, generate following schemes:

- $x_{n+1}=\frac12\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)$ for computing $\sqrt a$
- $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)$ for computing $a^{-1}$

what I understand is, the square root of $a$ is the number of $x$ which satisfies the following equations:
$$\sqrt x=\sqrt a\implies\sqrt x-\sqrt a=0$$
Now, letting $f(x)=\sqrt x-\sqrt a$ , we can apply newton's raphson method:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{\sqrt x_n-\sqrt a}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x_n}}=-x_n+2\sqrt a\sqrt x_n$$

Which seems not the correct form for what they asked. Even same for second one also. Another question is, "When I write program for second one, it always blow up to infinity for any number $>1$". Is there any typo in $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)$ for computing $a^{-1}$?

Comment: A small question: why would you use a sequence requiring to compute $\sqrt{a}$ to compute $\sqrt{a}$ ? :) And another one. Let $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Assume $(x_n)$ converges to $l$, what can you say about $f$ and $l$ ?

Comment: Also, $\sqrt{a}$ is the positive root of $x^2-a=0$ provided $a \ge 0$

Comment: To be honest, I also think why I need to iterative method to get $\sqrt a$, but the instructor give us that for fortran code (only use NR to get the scheme and implement in fortran) :) @nicomezi

Comment: It is a toy example. Imagine you do not have a function on your calculator retuning the square root. How would you compute it efficiently and systematically for all real positive numbers ? And, how does your calculator actually evaluate it ?

Answer (score 2):

The method shown as

$$
x_{n+1}=\frac 12\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)
$$

comes from considering the zeros of $f(x) = x^2-a$. It converges to $\pm \sqrt a$

A method to obtain $a^{-1}$, considering $f(x) = x^2-\frac{1}{a^2}$  can be posed as

$$
x_{n+1} = \frac 12\left(x_n+\frac{1}{a^2 x_n}\right)
$$

converging to $\pm a^{-1}$

NOTE

A method to compute reciprocals without the use of reciprocals can be obtained by considering $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}-a^2$ when the fixed point is obtained by iterating

$$
x_{n+1}=-\frac{x_n}{2}(a^2x_n^2-3)
$$

It is assumed known $\frac 12 = 0.5$

EDIT

The convergence for the second method $(a^{-1})$ can be justified analyzing the sufficient convergence condition which follows. If in

$$
x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n),\ x_{n} = \phi(x_{n-1}),\Rightarrow x_{n+1}-x_n = \phi'(\xi)(x_n-x_{n-1})
$$

we have that if $|\phi'(\xi)| < 1$ the sequence converges. Follows the graphics for $\phi'(\xi)$ when $a = 3$.

[image]

Comment: @CarlChristian Included a proper algorithm.

Comment: This is a improvement. However, there are two reasons why we normally would write is as $x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \frac{1}{2} x_n (1-a^2x_n^2)$. Firstly, subtractive cancellation in the correction term is irrelevant, because it only occurs when $x_n$ is close to the root in which case we only need the first few significant figures of the correction. Secondly, we can use the term $(1-a^2x^2)$ to detect when to terminate the iteration.

Comment: @Cesareo Thanks for your answer. I get where I messing up. But the blow up at infinity occur for inverse program (When I use the second iterative form to calculate inverse of a). Could you say something on that?

Comment: @falamiw Included an additional note.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of $a$ is not the number that satisfies $\sqrt x=\sqrt a$ (this is $a$ itself). It is the positive number that satisfies $x=\sqrt a$, or $x^2=a$.

Iterative methods have a domain of convergence, meaning that for some starting values they can fail to converge. Convergence is ensured when the distance to the root decreases on every iteration.

In the case of the inverse, you should ensure that $2-ax>0$ to keep positive estimates, hence the initial values must no be too large. For instance, it works well with $a=2,x_0=0.1$, giving the iterates

$$0.1,0.18,0.2952,0.41611392,0.4859262511645,0.4996038591874,0.4999996861449\cdots$$

---

A simple way to find good initial values is to determine the integer power of $2$ closest to the given $a$, let $2^n$. Then

$$\sqrt a\approx 2^{n/2}\text{ or }\sqrt2\,2^{(n-1)/2}$$

and

$$a^{-1}\approx 2^{-n}.$$